# How to detect nearby devices with Bluetooth LE in iOS 7.1 both in background and foreground?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have an app that needs to detect a nearby (in range for Bluetooth LE) devices running the same application and iOS 7.1. I've considered two alternatives for the detection:

1. Having the devices act as iBeacons and detect iBeacons in range
2. Using CoreBluetooth (like in Vicinity implementation [here](https://github.com/Instrument/Vicinity)) to create a BLE peripheral, advertise that and scan the peripherals

It seems that the option 1 is out of the question because:

- It may take at least 15 minutes for iOS to detect entering a beacon region when the application is running background (iOS 7.1)

Option 2 seems the way to go, but there are some difficulties regarding the implementation:

- iOS seems to change the peripheral UUID in advertisement packets after a certain period of time (around 15 minutes?). This means that it's not directly possible to identify the advertising device from the advertisement broadcast signal.

Regarding this, I have the following questions:

- Are there any other methods of implementing the nearby device detection I haven't considered?
- Is it possible to identify the device through advertising (or by some other means) so that option 2 would work?

Answer (score 24):

I found a way to make this work Core Bluetooth (option 2), the procedure is roughly the following:

- The application *advertises itself* with an encoded device unique identifier in `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` (when the broadcasting application runs foreground) and a characteristic that provides the device unique identifier through a Bluetooth LE service (when the broadcasting application runs background)
- At the same time, the application *scans other peripherals* with the same service.

The advertising works as follows:

- For the other devices to be able to identify this device, I use a per-device unique UUID (I'm using Urban Airship's `[UAUtils deviceID]`, because it's the device identifier in other parts of the program, also - but you might as well use any unique ID implementation).
- When the application is running foreground, I can pass the device unique ID *directly in the advertisement packet* by using `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey`. The standard UUID representation is too long, so I use a shortened form of the UUID as follows:

  ```
  + (NSString *)shortenedDeviceID
  {
      NSString *deviceID = [UAUtils deviceID];

      NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:deviceID];
      uuid_t uuidBytes;
      [uuid getUUIDBytes:uuidBytes];

      NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:uuidBytes length:16];
      NSString *base64 = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
      NSString *encoded = [[[base64
                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"_"]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"-"]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@""];
      return encoded;
  }
  ```
- When the application is running background, the advertisement packet gets stripped and `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` is not passed along anymore. For this, the application needs to publish a *characteristic* that provides the unique device identifier:

  ```
  - (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral
  {
      if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
          [self startAdvertising];

          if (peripheralManager) {
              CBUUID *serviceUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_IDENTIFIER_SERVICE_UUID];
              CBUUID *characteristicUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_IDENTIFIER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID];
              CBMutableCharacteristic *characteristic =
              [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:characteristicUUID
                                                 properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
                                                      value:[[MyUtils shortenedDeviceID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
              CBMutableService *service = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:serviceUUID primary:YES];
              service.characteristics = @[characteristic];
              [peripheralManager addService:service];
          }
      }
  }
  ```

The scanning works as follows:

- You start to scan peripherals with the certain service UUID as follows (notice that you need to specify the service UUID, because otherwise background scan fails to find the device):

  ```
  [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_IDENTIFIER_SERVICE_UUID]]
      options:scanOptions];
  ```
- When a device is discovered at `- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
   advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI` you check that if `advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey]` exists and try to convert it back to UUID form like this:

  ```
  + (NSString *)deviceIDfromShortenedDeviceID:(NSString *)shortenedDeviceID
  {
      if (!shortenedDeviceID)
          return nil;
      NSString *decoded = [[[shortenedDeviceID
                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@"/"]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"+"]
                           stringByAppendingString:@"=="];

      NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:decoded options:0];
      if (!data)
          return nil;

      NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDBytes:[data bytes]];

      return uuid.UUIDString;
  }
  ```
- If the conversion fails you know the broadcasting device is in background, and you need to *connect* to the device to read the *characteristic* that provides the unique identifier. For this you need to use `[self.central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];` (with `peripheral.delegate = self;` and implement a chain of delegate methods as follows:

  ```
  - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
  {
      [peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_IDENTIFIER_SERVICE_UUID]]];
  }

  - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
  {
      if (!error) {
          for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
              if ([service.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:DEVICE_IDENTIFIER_SERVICE_UUID]) {
                  NSLog(@"Service found with UUID: %@", service.UUID);
                  [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_IDENTIFIER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]] forService:service];
              }
          }
      }
  }

  - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
  {
      if (!error) {
          for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
              if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_IDENTIFIER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
                  [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
              }
          }
      }
  }

  - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
  {
      if (!error) {
          NSString *shortenedDeviceID = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSString *deviceId = [MyUtils deviceIDfromShortenedDeviceID:shortenedDeviceID];
          NSLog(@"Got device id: %@", deviceId);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: can a device scan and advertise at the same time?

Comment: This post was extremely helpful, thanks!  One note, in didDiscoverPeripheral if the peripheral that's discovered is in the background at the time of discovery the service UUID can be found in the advertisementData using CBAdvertisementDataOverflowServiceUUIDsKey instead of CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey.

Comment: Second note, before connecting via connectPeripheral you'll need to keep a reference to the peripheral you're connecting to.

Comment: Thanks for the notes, I'll test them and update my answer correspondingly.

Comment: I've found that the `LocalName` key can only reliably be 8 chars when in the foreground. I've found the length transmitted varies too - possibly because of other BLE apps on the device. Just don't rely on it being any longer than 8 chars, and of course its not available in the background.

Comment: could someone confirm that this code still works on the latest iOS?  i've been having trouble getting scan + advertise to work at the same time.  thx

Comment: I am doing exactly the same in iOS 12+

Sadly after some time in the background, even when I try to connect to the peripheral, I do not see the service in the didDiscoverServices delegate.

@MarkusRautopuro have you tested this code with a device being in the background and it's service being discoverable after a couple of minutes?